How to read multiple netcdf files from GCP bucket storage in Python
I have the following code that lists all the files matching a naming pattern in my Google Cloud bucket storage
from google.cloud import storage

def list_files(bucket_name, prefix):
    """Lists all the files in the specified directory/folder in a GCS bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix, match_glob="data/*CanESM2_historical*.nc")  # prefix filters for a specific folder

    file_paths = []
    for blob in blobs:
        print(blob.name)
        file_paths.append(f'gcs://{bucket_name}/{blob.name}')


    return file_paths

I want to read all of them into one dataset using xarray.open_mfdataset as I am already  doing it locally with
ds_1971_2000_historical = xr.open_mfdataset(f'{local_data_dir}*CanESM2_historical*.nc')
What  I have tried:
Reading them with
fs = fsspec.filesystem('gcs')

# Open the dataset
ds = xarray.open_mfdataset(file_paths, engine='netcdf4', concat_dim='time', combine='nested')

which gives me an
OSError: [Errno -36] NetCDF: Invalid argument: 'gcs://agrex_data/data/pr_AFR-44_CCCma-CanESM2_historical_r1i1p1_CCCma-CanRCM4_r2_day_19710101-19751231.nc'
for the very first path in the file_paths list
How can I get it done?
